# Make GTK3 applications use the GTK2 dialog for font selection?

Tags: fonts, gtk3, gtk2

I prefer the user interface of the font-selection dialog of GTK2 to that of GTK3. How can I make GTK3 applications use the GTK2 dialog?

EDIT: Unfortunately, Gnome doesn't let me take screenshots of the dialogs, so I am posting links.

The font-selection dialog of GTK2 is on top of [this page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkFontSelectionDialog.html), whereas the font-selection dialog of GTK3 is on top of [this page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFontChooserDialog.html). I prefer the interface of the former dialog, so I would like all applications to use it instead of the latter dialog whenever I need to select a font.

Comment: You may wish to read [this](http://catb.org./~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal).

Comment: @theGtknerd I have added links to the two dialogs. Hopefully, now my question is clearer.

Comment: You are asking `How do I make X do Y`, when you might better ask `How can I add feature to Y` or maybe even file a bug report with Gtk3?

Comment: In short, what you are asking isn't possible, so you may want to use a different approach.

Comment: Offtopic, but you can take a screenshot of a modal dialog box by running the nasty thing inside Xephyr (eg. `Xephyr :15 & sleep 1; DISPLAY=:15 gnome-app`). Probably not for long -- there's a systemd module in the works which will stop any other interaction in the universe while a Gnome dialog box is active.

Comment: It is possible to write a LD_PRELOAD hack that will override the gtk_font_chooser_* functions with wrappers to the interface from gtk2, but that looks like a lot of work to fix what is insultingly broken design in the first place: why aren't the dialogs separate processes using standard [icccm](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/specs/ICCCM/icccm.html) to communicate with the app?